# Overwrite the within 30 days in FIlteredViews

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a SRSS report using a SQL Query that uses that FilteredViews to allow for the report to use the "Run on current record". This works great but it adds a "Last X Days" and sets it to 30. It there someway to change that or better yet, get rid of it altogether? This is my query for reference:

```
SELECT        CRMAF_Quote.QuoteNumber, CRMAF_Quote.Name, CRMAF_Quote.CreatedOn, CRMAF_Quote.CustomerIdName, CRMAF_Quote.OwnerIdName, 
                         CRMAF_Quote.Name AS Expr1, CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_Line1, CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_Line2, CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_Line3, CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_StateOrProvince, 
                         CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_PostalCode, CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_Telephone, CRMAF_Quote.BillTo_Fax, CRMAF_QuoteDetail.lineitemnumber, CRMAF_QuoteDetail.Quantity,
                         CRMAF_QuoteDetail.productdescription, CRMAF_QuoteDetail.BaseAmount, CRMAF_QuoteDetail.ExtendedAmount, CRMAF_Quote.DiscountAmount, CRMAF_Quote.TotalTax, CRMAF_Quote.TotalAmount, 
                         CRMAF_Quote.RevisionNumber, CRMAF_SystemUser.Address1_Telephone1, 
                         CRMAF_SystemUser.InternalEMailAddress, CRMAF_Product.productnumber, CRMAF_Product.Name AS ProductName
FROM            FilteredQuote as CRMAF_Quote JOIN
                         FilteredQuoteDetail as CRMAF_QuoteDetail ON CRMAF_Quote.QuoteId = CRMAF_QuoteDetail.QuoteId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         FilteredProduct AS CRMAF_Product ON CRMAF_QuoteDetail.productid =  CRMAF_Product.productid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         FilteredSystemUser as CRMAF_SystemUser ON CRMAF_Quote.OwnerId = CRMAF_SystemUser.SystemUserId
```

Attached is a screenshot of the 30 days it adds.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your list of available reports - you should be able to select your report and then from the ribbon select Edit Default Filter. There you can change or eliminate the filter that automatically is added.